# drupal 8 display block in view footer/header

Tags: drupal-views, drupal-8, drupal-blocks

in drupal 8 core views, in any view you can add header or footer field with "Rendered entity - Custom block". When you do so, it asks for the block id, which appearently is machine name of the block.
A search form block has an id equal to `bartik_search` and that will make the search box to display. 
But i have my own custom block created and it has Machine name: `modallink` and i want it to display instead.
Problem is, when i enter `modallink` into the "block id" box, it doesn't work. Nothing gets rendered.

What is ID of my custom `modallink` block?
Am I using the "Rendered entity - Custom block" field incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

It's horrible, but here is what seems to work:

- Go to structure -> block layout
- place your block in random area of your theme
- go to the page settings and hide the block on all pages
  but some invalid url (for example enter 'none'
- go to your view, place the block in header / footer
- click the checkbox for 'bypass access checks' in the setting-popup.

Comment: Are you answering a question with a question?

Comment: no, i was making a (wrong) suggestion, while asking a question about the first answer to this question.

Comment: Good idea but if you restrict pages where the block will show or disable it in the block layout page it will not show in the view header/footer!